# Variants network multiplayer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer, game-development

We are developing a rogulike, Hack & Slash RPG on Unity. Tell me, please, what technology options can I use for network multiplayer? Players will be able to simultaneously control their characters in real time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use Photon Network and its PUN 2 version. You can use it for free if there is less than 20 players in the same time in your game, then you need to pay.

You can check their website:
https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/index.html

Or try to use this good tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/1142814-introduction-to-multiplayer-games-with-unity-and-photon

It is globally simple to use but not trivial, so don't hesitate to create new ticket if you encounter new issues.

Comment: Do you know if UNet has been fully replaced now and where can one find tutorial on how to use the new Networking system?

Comment: UNet is replaced by Mirror basically. But I have no clue about the new multiplayer system built with unity. I heard of it multiples times but I don't know if it is still working or if there is documentation about it